# Can't evaluate Clojure web project code using Vim and tpope's Fireplace plugin?

Tags: vim, clojure, vim-plugin

I've installed the Leiningen Clojure project tool using: `brew install leiningen` (the REPL works fine).

I wanted to use Vim to write some Clojure code and so I've installed the following plugins:

- https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/
- https://github.com/tpope/vim-classpath
- https://github.com/tpope/vim-clojure-static/
- https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim
- https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim

I opened three terminal consoles and execute commands in this order:

1. `lein new compojure my-project`
2. `lein repl`
3. `cd my-project && vim`

Within Vim I first connect to the REPL...

- `:Connect nrepl://127.0.0.1:60356`

...then I open the `my-project/src/my_project/handler.clj` file and press `cpp` (which I think is aliased to `:Eval` whilst my cursor is on the first character of the first opening parenthesis.

At this point I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate my_project/handler__init.class or my_project/handler.clj on classpath: clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

I've not been able to find any appropriate solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for lein to properly set up your classpath, it must be started inside the project directory. Change directory into the my-project directory before starting lein repl.